# Firebase Dynamic Links Don't Work in Release APK

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-dynamic-links

I recently started using Firebase Dynamic Links in my Android app. Everything works great when I run my app with a debug APK. When I click on a dynamic link, it opens my app on the correct screen with the intent filter I set up in my manifest.

Here's what it looks like in the debug version:
[Correct result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03AmL.jpg)

However, I have noticed that the dynamic link doesn't work when I generate a release APK and try to click the same link. Instead the link opens in a browser first before opening my app at the launcher activity which isn't the activity I specified with my intent filter.

Here's the same test in the release version:
[Incorrect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1Yj3.jpg)

I'm assuming this is a problem with my build settings but it could be something else. I haven't been able to identify it. I tried disabling proguard in my app's build.gradle file but that had no effect.

For reference, here's the buildTypes snippet of my build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
    debug{
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Also the proguard-rules.pro file is currently empty. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Have you created a SHA256 key based on your production keystore? You have to add it to your project inside the Firebase console in order to have app links enabled.

Reference to documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive#app_links